# Parsing problems with nested JSON list/dictionaries

Tags: python, json

I am writing a script to create a csv based on a parsed JSON.  I am able to read the JSON, but get hung up with a TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict.

I have a previous version that is working, but with a different JSON, so the structure is slightly different, and I am working on my reverse engineering skills, but am stumped on extracting with the slight differences.

JSON is structured thus:

```
{
 "league": {
   "games": {
     "0": [
      {
       "game": {
          "game_number": "game_1",
          "season": "2019",
          "start_time": "Sat, 13 Apr 2019 23:00:00", 
          "team_id": [
              {
              "away_team": "team_x"
              },
              {
              "home_team": "team_a"
              },
           ],
          },
         },
        ],
       },
      },
}
```

```
data = json_parsed['league']['games'][0]

with open('./soccer_041519.csv', 'w+') as csvFile:

    for game in data:
        gameid = data[game]['game_number']
        start_time = data[game]['start_time']
        home_team_id = data[game]['home_team']
        away_team_id = data[game]['away_team']
csvFile.write("%s @ %s,%s, ,%s\n"%(away_team_id, home_team_id, gameid, start_time))     


The values should be written to the CSV
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  `"game_number": "game_1"` needs a trailing comma, as do the next two items.  Also, the dictionaries in `team_id` need to be separated with commas.

Answer (score 1):

a few things I've noticed with the json data:

1. Missing tons of commas
2. You're trying to call an element by it's index value 0, when it's
   a
       key of `"0"`

So fixing 1:

```
{
 "league": {
   "games": {
     "0": [
      {
       "game": {
          "game_number": "game_1"   <---- need comma
          "season": "2019"    <-----need comma
          "start_time": "Sat, 13 Apr 2019 23:00:00"  <-----need comma
          "team_id": [
              {
              "away_team": "team_x"
              }   <-----need comma
              {
              "home_team": "team_a"
              }
           ]
          }
         }
        ]
       }
      }
}
```

So fix that:

```
json_parsed = {"league": {
   "games": {
     "0": [
      {
       "game": {
          "game_number": "game_1",
          "season": "2019",
          "start_time": "Sat, 13 Apr 2019 23:00:00" ,
          "team_id": [
              {
              "away_team": "team_x"
              },
              {
              "home_team": "team_a"
              }
           ]
          }
         }
        ]
       }
      }
}
```

Fixing 2:

```
data = json_parsed['league']['games']['0']
```

Then for your loop:

```
for game in data:
    gameid = game['game_number']
    start_time = game['start_time']
    home_team_id = game['home_team_id']
    away_team_id = game['away_team_id']
```

Comment: That give the following error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soccer_csv_create.py", line 25, in <module>
    gameid = data[game]['game_number']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict

Answer (score 0):

```
for game in data:
    gameid = data[game]['game_number']
```

You don't need to refer to `data`, as your loop already gets each specific game.

Use `gameid = game['game']['game_number']` instead.

Also, your use of the `team_id` list is confusing.  Why is it a list?  Usually a list is used when you don't know how many items there will be, but in this case it seems like you do know that -- there will always be one home team and one away team, right?

It seems like a single dictionary would be a better way to represent `team_id`:

```
"team_id": {
    "away_team": "team_x"
    "home_team": "team_a"
}
```

Or, even better, why does this sub-dictionary exist at all?  It seems like `away_team_id` and `home_team_id` could be elements in the main-level dictionary.  Why do they need to be segregated away on their own?

Comment: I don't know why the JSON is that way, but it is.  Now the error has changed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soccer_csv_create.py", line 27, in <module>
    home_team_id = game['game']['team_ids']['home_team_id']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: That's because `game['game']['team_ids']` is a list, but you're trying to treat it like a dictionary.

Comment: This not a JSON that I created, this i s just what the API spits out.  I am able to get some of the information out now, but it doesn't seem to be looping through.  It is only returning info for one game, and there are many.
   ```home_team_id = game['game']['team_ids'][1]['home_team_id']```
   ```away_team_id = game['game']['team_ids'][0]['away_team_id']```